# How to settings, then at update just twice run down?

Tags: php, mysql

This sql :

```
if($_POST['adat']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' ");


    foreach($_POST['page_ids'] as $page){
        $pa = $page;

        if ($pa){
            mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  AND page_id = '$page'  LIMIT 2 ");
        }

    }   
}
```

I like, that When selected page, then if more page selected even just let it be two update?
I try `order by user_id limit 2`, or simple `limit 2` , but this not working.

Comment: It's not clear what you want... can you add any more information?

Comment: I would like to see more pages are selected do not all go up but only to update them, I want to limit the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of limit

```
if($_POST['adat']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' ");


    foreach($_POST['page_ids'] as $page){
        $pa = $page;

        if ($pa){
            mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  AND page_id = '$page'  LIMIT 2 ");
        }

    }
}
```

You have to just use break keyword behind loop

```
if($_POST['adat']){
    mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '0' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]' ");

    $i=1;
    foreach($_POST['page_ids'] as $page){
        $pa = $page;

        if ($pa){
            mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  AND page_id = '$page'");
        }
     if($i>=2){
        break;
     }  
     $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You get the point, this is good, thank you very much my friend!!

Answer (score 0):

simply do it by

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET page_value = '1' WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[user_id]'  AND page_id FIND_IN_SET($_POST['page_ids'])");
```

there is no need to do it in loop.

Comment: -1 feeding the help vampire

Comment: This is not good, I want to choose more than one error page for update run at only two

Comment: @user2568284 it perfect just add limit at end.It is not good the other people write exact code for you .you should something need to do yourself.